# magento - HTTPS on frontend with all pages

Tags: magento, ssl, https

I have Magento 1.9.2.0.
With this version, enabling SSL only works with account pages, and order pages.
BTW it is funny the english text in system configuration only says
"Use Secure URLs in Frontend"   Yes/No

but the french translation is more explicit:
"Utiliser des URLs sécurisées pour le front office (mon compte et passage de commande)"
the part between brackets means "my account and order pages".

is there any workaround to apply HTTPS everywhere?

I had a look to the way the menu is displayed, it leverages this from the Core:

`this->getUrlModel()->getCategoryUrl($this)`

this does not take into account whether SSL is required or not, that also confirms the limitation.
I might need to override this method at least for the menu.
and then I need to do the same for links to other pages (product detail etc...)

is this feature only part to magento 2.0?

thanks,

Rod

note: of course a htaccess redirection is NOT the solution I am looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Goto systems->Configuration->General->Web->unsecure and secure->base URL  put https://www.yourdomain.com / in  both first try only with secure and SSL should be SSL_OFFLOADED if its work then don't change unsecured URL  if not then you need to change both base URL

Comment: well, thanks I didn't realize I had to set the secured URL into the unsecure field.it seems like it also applies to admin pages even thought I didn't check the flag to apply HTTPS to admin pages. I will double check carefully that everything works as expected. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is the expected behavior, to have the site serve over https protocol you can set the base secure and base unsecure urls to `https://yourdomain.com/`